# Sorting rows then sorting columns preserves the sorting of rows

Tags: matrices, puzzle, sorting, popular-math

From Peter Winkler's book:

> Given a matrix, prove that after first sorting each row, then sorting each column, each row remains sorted.

For example: starting with

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -5 \\
4 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Sorting each row individually and in ascending order gives

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 2 \\
-5 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then sorting each column individually in ascending order gives

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 0 & 1 \\
-3 & 1 & 2 \\
-1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

And notice the rows are still individually sorted, in ascending order.

I was trying to find a 'nice'  proof that does not involve messy index comparisons... but I cannot find one!

Comment: I don't understand what the rows will remain sorted means.  When you rearrange the columns you aren't doing anything to the cells in terms of their row positions so of course the rows remain sorted.

Comment: I will add an example to my question

Comment: How are you sorting?

Comment: Oh, I get it.  You are sorting lexigraphically.  The rows will remain lexigraphic.  That is true and not trivial.

Comment: Given a row, say you sort it in ascending order. Repeat for each row. Now take the resulting matrix, and do the same for each individual column. Then each row of the resulting matrix still  has its entries in ascending order.

Comment: Oh you sort the *cells* in each row not  the entire rows as whole rows.

Comment: You need messy index.  But messy index shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: Hopefully the example clarifies my statement now

Comment: @fleablood: Do you consider my answer to be a counter-example to "needing messy index"? =)

Comment: Well... no, I assume  the OP would have considered your answer to be messy indexing.  But apparently not..  I don't consider messy indexing to be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that you can start from after the first step. Specifically, you only need to prove that, given an arbitrary matrix where each row is already in ascending order, sorting each column in ascending order keeps each row sorted. Here is a very neat trick to do this.

Let $m$ be the number of columns. For each $k$ from $1$ to $m$, sort the rows of the subarray from column $k$ to column $m$ in increasing order of the element in column $k$. (Each row of the subarray stays together.) We do this sorting by bubble sort. We maintain the invariant that the elements in each row stays sorted. This invariant is trivially true when $k = 1$. When $k > 1$, and we perform a swap involving rows $p$ and $(p+1)$, consider the elements in those rows and in the columns $(k-1)$ and $k$:

> $\cdots \quad a \quad d \quad \cdots_1$
>
> $\cdots \quad b \quad c \quad \cdots_2$

By the invariance we have $a \le b \le c$ and the swap is only done because $c \le d$. After the swap we have:

> $\cdots \quad a \quad c \quad \cdots_2$
>
> $\cdots \quad b \quad d \quad \cdots_1$

And the invariance is preserved since $a \le c$ and $b \le d$. Look! No index chasing!

Comment: Really neat many thanks !!!!

Comment: @user3203476: You're welcome! This trick of incrementally sorting is very useful, since in some sense preserving an invariant over a swap is the bare minimum that you need to preserve the invariant over sorting.

Comment: Not getting this. You show that when you bubblesort a column, it remains entrywise $\geq$ to the column to its left. Shouldn't you also show that it remains entrywise $\leq$ to the column to its right? This is probably analogous, but needs to be at least said.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: No, read the second sentence in my second paragraph again. It does not say we bubblesort a column. In fact, I explicitly emphasized that in the bracketed third sentence. Also, if you bubble-sort a single column at a time, it will fail, unlike what I describe.

Comment: What does "Each row of the subarray stays together" mean? And how does sorting columns $k$ to $m$ help?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I'm not sure what you're reading. The second sentence says very clearly "**sort the rows of** the subarray from column k to column m".

Comment: I don't get it. Aren't the rows already increasing? If so, why sort them again?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: You should spend more time reading what I wrote carefully, as it is 100% clear already. If you don't get it, don't just assume there is something wrong (as you did from your first comment). There is only one way to parse the second sentence: "For each k from 1 to m { sort { the rows of { the subarray from column k to column m } } ( in increasing order of { the element in column k } ) }". Frankly, this is basic English, just like "sort these apples in increasing order of size".

Answer (score 2):

Let's say after sorting, the new matrix is $A$ with m rows and n columns. We have to prove that

\begin{equation}
A_{ij}\leq A_{ik},\, \forall j  \leq k
\end{equation}
where  $A_{xy}$ is element at $x_{th}$ row and $y_{th}$ column.

Here we know that there are at least $i$ elements (including $A_{ik}$) in column $k$ which are less than or equal to $A_{ik}$ and corresponding to their initial positions we have $i$ elements in column $j$ which are at most those elements therefore at least $i$ elements exist in column $j$ which are less than or equal to $A_{ik}$, Hence when column j is sorted
\begin{equation}
A_{ij} \leq A_{ik}
\end{equation}

Comment: This solution is somewhat unclear; please distinguish between submatrices and elements.